# Computing the CDF with QAE in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, amplitude-amplification, quantum-computing-for-finance, quantum-circuit

I want to load a lognormal distribution and then use an IntegerComparator to flip a qubit ($|0\rangle$ to $|1\rangle$) if its value is less than a threshold. Then I want to use an Quantum Amplitude Estimation algorithm to calculate the probability of measuring $|1\rangle$.

My code so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from qiskit import Aer, QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, execute
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import IterativeAmplitudeEstimation
from qiskit.circuit.library import LogNormalDistribution, IntegerComparator



num_uncertainty_qubits = 3

S = 100
vol = 0.4
r = 0.04
T = 3*(30/365)


mu = np.log(S) + (r-0.5*vol**2)*T
sigma = vol*np.sqrt(T)

mean = np.exp(mu - 0.5*sigma**2)
variance = (np.exp(sigma**2)-1)*np.exp(2*mu + sigma**2)
stddev = np.sqrt(variance)

low = np.maximum(0, mean-3*stddev)
high = mean + 3*stddev

uncertainty_model = LogNormalDistribution(num_uncertainty_qubits, mu=mu, sigma=sigma**2, bounds=(low, high))

# 3 qubit LogNormalDistribution model
uncertainty_model = LogNormalDistribution(3, mu=mu, sigma=sigma, bounds=(low, high))

# function to create the quantum circuit of the IntegerComparator and the uncertainty model
# x_eval is the threshold below which the qubit should be flipped
def get_cdf_circuit(x_eval):
    qr_state = QuantumRegister(uncertainty_model.num_qubits, 'state')
    qr_obj = QuantumRegister(1, 'obj')
    qr_comp = QuantumRegister(2, 'compare')
    state_preparation = QuantumCircuit(qr_state, qr_obj, qr_comp)
    
    state_preparation.append(uncertainty_model, qr_state)
    comparator = IntegerComparator(uncertainty_model.num_qubits, x_eval, geq=False)
    
    state_preparation.append(comparator, qr_state[:]+qr_obj[:]+qr_comp[:])
    
    return state_preparation

# Function to implement the Amplitude Estimation algorithm

def run_ae_for_cdf(x_eval, epsilon=0.01, alpha=0.05, simulator='qasm_simulator'):

    state_preparation = get_cdf_circuit(x_eval)

    ae_var = IterativeAmplitudeEstimation(state_preparation=state_preparation,
                                          epsilon=epsilon, alpha=alpha,
                                          objective_qubits=[len(qr_state)]) 
    result_var = ae_var.run(quantum_instance=Aer.get_backend(simulator), shots=100)
    
    return result_var['estimation']
```

Broadly speaking, I want to flip the objective qubit to $|1\rangle$ if the state is less than or equal to x_eval.

On running this, I'm getting the same amplitude estimation every time, even when I use different threshold values.

I'm missing something. Please help me out.

PS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHyDM.jpg This is the link to the QuantumCircuit. P(X) is the LogNormalDistribution and Cmp is the comparator.

PPS: Using LinearAmplitudeFunction to compare floating numbers:

```
def get_comparator(threshold, num_qubits, low, high):
    breakpoints = [low, threshold]
    offsets = [0,0]
    slopes = [0,0]
    f_min = 1
    f_max = 0
    objective = LinearAmplitudeFunction(
        num_qubits,
        slopes,
        offsets,
        domain=(low, high),
        image=(f_min, f_max),
        breakpoints=breakpoints
    )
    return objective
```

Comment: For me your code works, though I had to change `len(qr_state)` to `3` because `qr_state` is not globally defined. If I run `run_ae_for_cdf` for the values 2, 3 and 4 I obtain 0.129,
0.309 and 0.489, respectively. Can you post the entire code, including imports and how you call the function?

Comment: I got rid of the individual quantum registers so that there isn't any confusion. And I changed `len(qr_state)` to  `3`. However, for all different `x_eval` values, I'm getting `1` as the output which shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Cryoris I've uploaded the entire code. I just call run_ae_for_cdf(70) to check the code. PS: 70 is just an example, can be any integer value.

Comment: For me your code works, see the output in the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be also useful to see your Quantum Circuit using `%matplotlib inline`
and `qc.draw('mpl')` to see whether all gates are correctly connected. I had a similar problem with QAE and figured out by using this method that the order of qubits I tried to append the `IntegerComparator` onto was wrong. Cheers

Comment: I've added a link to the quantum circuit. Let me know what you think.

Comment: What values are you selecting for mu=mu, sigma=sigma, bounds=(low, high)? If I use the default values and do not define particular values I get 0.113, 0.284, 0.464 for x_eval = [2, 3, 4].

Comment: I updated the link to the decomposed quantum circuit diagram. I've also added the entire code. Let me know.

Comment: Please note that with `num_uncertainty_qubits = 3` you will only be able to reflect values up to `7`. Your lower and upper bound, as well as the `x_eval=70` are not within that limit. You either need to increase the number of uncertainty qubits or scale down your problem to be within that limit.

Comment: This solves it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am also working with `IterativeAmplitudeEstimation` in `qiskit`. I was able to run QAE for 'Credit Analysis with Quantum Computing' as described in

https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/finance/09_credit_risk_analysis.html

by preparing the quantum circuits from scratch. But when using the libraries as described on the page I got many errors (see below). I guess some of the libraries have simply just moved?

From which library are you loading `LogNormalDistribution`? I use

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import IntegerComparator
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms.amplitude_estimators.iqae import IterativeAmplitudeEstimation
from qiskit.aqua.components.uncertainty_models import NormalDistribution
from qiskit.aqua.components.uncertainty_models import LogNormalDistribution
```

I for example get the following error for `LogNormalDistribution` when I load the model from  `qiskit.aqua.components.uncertainty_models`

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bounds'
```

or `'LogNormalDistribution' object has no attribute 'num_qubits'`

I hope to get the libraries running to help you dig into your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I imported the LogNormalDistribution from qiskit.circuit.library

Comment: I reinstalled qiskit and now all libraries work perfectly. I use `from qiskit.circuit.library import LogNormalDistribution
from qiskit.circuit.library import WeightedAdder
from qiskit.circuit.library import IntegerComparator
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import IterativeAmplitudeEstimation`

Answer (score 1):

I had to exchange `len(qr_state)` with `num_uncertainty_qubits` in the code you posted

```
    # in run_ae_for_cdf
    ae_var = IterativeAmplitudeEstimation(state_preparation=state_preparation,
                                          epsilon=epsilon, alpha=alpha,
                                          objective_qubits=[num_uncertainty_qubits])
```

but then for me it seems to work just fine.

The output is

```
# executing your script with python -i and then:
>>> run_ae_for_cdf(1)
0.03904972139433151
>>> run_ae_for_cdf(3)
0.35743729093195115
>>> run_ae_for_cdf(6)
0.8437041835749457
>>> run_ae_for_cdf(70)
0.9999743710958622
```

You have 3 qubits in your system so the largest integer you can represent is 7 ($ = 2^3 - 1$) so for values $\geq 8$ the CDF should be 1. That's because the CDF $F(x)$ is the probability of measuring a state smaller than $x$:
$$
F(x) = \mathrm{Pr}(\text{measure any state } |i\rangle \text{ with } i \leq x)
$$
Since $i$ can reach 7 at most, we should see
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases} \text{some increasing function, if } x \leq 7 \\
1 \text{, if } x > 7 
\end{cases}
$$

With your code you can generate the following plot

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> i = list(range(20))
>>> f = [run_ae_for_cdf(val) for val in i]
>>> plt.axhline(1, color="k", linestyle="-")  # the max we reach
>>> plt.axvline(8, color="k", linestyle=":")  # from here on it should be 1
>>> plt.xlabel("x")
>>> plt.ylabel("CDF, $F(x)$")
>>> plt.show()
```

which seems to meet what we expected.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Also, is there any way to compare floating numbers in qiskit? I mean instead of the 7 that was taken in this example, can I use a float? I've added a code block where I tried implementing the same using LinearAmplitudeFunction with threshold as a floating number.